# Boolean handling in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean-logic

I have following code in my php script:

```
if ( $x != 'some_val_1' &&  $y['index']->title != "some_val_2" &&  $y['index']->title != "some_val_3" ) {
    // Do something.
  }
```

In the code shown above, `index` may/may not be set and thus when it is not set this code throws a php notice.

I changed it to:

```
  if (isset($y['index']->title)) {   
    if ( $x != 'some_val_1' &&  $y['index']->title != "some_val_2" &&  $y['index']->title != "some_val_3" ) {
      // Do something.
    }
  }
```

However since the "Do something" part is set to work when `isset($y['index']->title` is *not equal* to `some_val_2` and `some_val_3`, the above does not work because the `isset()` condition I added skips the code.

So now the script does not throw notice but at the cost of completely changing the condition to something not desirable.

How can I change this code to not throw the PHP notice?

Comment: Use else if condition

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in different ways, I initialize the variables if they are not defined:

```
if (! isset($y['index']->title)) {
    $y['index']->title = '';
}

if ( $x != 'some_val_1' &&  $y['index']->title != "some_val_2" &&  $y['index']->title != "some_val_3" ) {
    // Do something.
}
```

*I prefer this way because I don't need to change my code and add `if` conditions (with `isset` for example) in all my program. I just add the conditions at the top of my code.*

Comment: I almost opted for your solution, but then realized that setting the value for `['index']->title` when it is not really required might cause issues.

Comment: @kmdhm What kind of issues? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with an array of objects, you can use the function `array_key_exists()`.

Your code will look like this:

```
if ( array_key_exists('index',$y) && $x != 'some_val_1' &&  $y['index']->title != 'some_val_2' &&  $y['index']->title != 'some_val_3' ) {
    // Do something.
}
```

You can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `isset` & `in_array` in this scenario.

```
if ( $x != 'some_val_1' 
    && isset($y['index']->title)  
    && !in_array($y['index']->title, array("some_val_2", "some_val_3") ) ) {
    // Do something.
}
```

The benefit of using `in_array` is that you validate case-sensitivity by passing `TRUE / FALSE` in the third parameter.